# Data on amount of students per university (and subject) in Germany

Tags: data-request, academia

Is there open data on the amount of students per university (and subject) in Germany?

I found some data on "Hochschulen" which seems quite outdated: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Studentenwerke_in_Deutschland. Optimally the data should be able to be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Found this overview. It gives a very detailed overview:

https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Gesellschaft-Umwelt/Bildung-Forschung-Kultur/Hochschulen/Publikationen/Downloads-Hochschulen/studierende-hochschulen-vorb-2110410198004.html

Edit: One can contact the "statistische Bundesamt" for additional data. It may require additional time and cost.